# How do I put two divs next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to put two divs next to each other, but I cannot find an effective way to do it. I want to set a sidebar menu next to an article. I tried floating one to the left, but all it does is create a huge gap between the two.
This is my code:

*CSS*

```css
div#divone {
     float:left;
     margin-left: 10%;
     border: 2px outset white;
     padding; 10px 10px 10px 10px;
     font-family; Times New Roman;
}
div#divtwo {
     float:right;
     margin-left: .1%;
     border: 2px outset white;
     padding; 10px 10px 10px 10px;
     font-family; Times New Roman;
}
```

*HTML*

```html
<div id="divone">
     <p>word</p>
</div>
<div id="divtwo">
     <p>word</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Float both divs left? http://jsfiddle.net/emturano/uju6pqL7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float:left` on the divs to bring them both together, and while you're doing that, why not put the common styles in one place, to make your CSS a little 'cleaner' ?

```css
div.floated {
  float: left;
  border: 2px outset white;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}

div#divone {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

div#divtwo {
  margin-left: .1%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="floated" id="divone">
    <p>word</p>
  </div>
  <div class="floated" id="divtwo">
    <p>word</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

here's a jsfiddle to represent it if you want to play around with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ya3L75xd/

Answer (score 0):

You should put `#divTwo { float:left }`

Answer (score 0):

float:left; for both `<div>` and they are next to each other.

Comment: I think you should add some flesh to the answer with sample code. A jsfiddle for example.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float: left;` on your `div#divone`.

Put the `div#divtwo` before the `div#divone` in the html.

Here's the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/nk2oLvgy/1/